# Redshift dateformat error when uploading date data

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to send json data to kinesis delivery stream and using lambda to process the data and send it to Redshift DB. I am getting this error error when sending the date data:

> Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS]

I have added `format as json 'auto' timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS'` to the copy command.

What should I do?

Example of shippedDate : `2020-04-02 05:32:37.044183`

Comment: Why are you using a timeformat of `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS`? Wouldn't it be more like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS`? See: [Datetime Format Strings - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html)

Comment: Hi, my issue was solved by adding "dateformat 'auto' ". Thanks for the help @John Rotenstein